# Delete and replace images in an backend extension controller under typo3 10 not working

Tags: php, typo3

I have an backend extension which works fine except the update function. The images are not being replaced. For the code below I get the error message for typo3 10:

> Argument 1 passed to
> TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceStorage::assureFileDeletePermissions()
> must implement interface TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileInterface, string
> given, called in
> /Users/myname/Sites/localhost/vah-f14/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Resource/ResourceStorage.php
> on line 1868

I also tried to implement `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileInterface` like this:

```php
/**
     * Replaces the existing file with the new file in the file system
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileInterface $existingFile
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $newFileReference
     * @return void
     */
    protected function replaceFile(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileInterface $existingFile, \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $newFileReference)
    {
        $storage = $existingFile->getStorage();
        $folder = $existingFile->getParentFolder();
        $fileName = $existingFile->getName();

        // Delete the existing file
        if ($existingFile instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileInterface) {
            $storage->deleteFile($folder->getCombinedIdentifier() . $fileName);
        } else {
            die('not working');
        }
        // Import the new file into the storage
        $newFile = $this->resourceFactory->importUploadedFile(
            $newFileReference->getOriginalResource()->getOriginalFile(),
            $folder->getCombinedIdentifier(),
            $fileName
        );

        // Update the file reference with the new file
        $newFileReference->setOriginalResource($newFile);
    }
```

but it gives me the same error message. Any help for this is very appreciated.

```php
/**
     * action update
     *
     * @param \Covisiomedia\PdfGenerator\Domain\Model\Pdfgenerator $pdfgenerator
     * @return string|object|null|void
     */
    public function updateAction(\Covisiomedia\PdfGenerator\Domain\Model\Pdfgenerator $pdfgenerator)
    {

        // Get the file objects associated with the model
        $profilbildObject = $pdfgenerator->getProfilbild();
        
        // Check if new files have been uploaded for each property
        if ($profilbildObject instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference && $profilbildObject->getOriginalResource()->getProperties()['replaceFile']) {
            $existingFileObject = $pdfgenerator->getProfilbild()->getOriginalResource()->getOriginalFile();
            $this->replaceFile($existingFileObject, $profilbildObject);

        }

        $this->saveAction($pdfgenerator);

        $this->addFlashMessage('The object was updated. Please be aware that this action is publicly accessible unless you implement an access check. See https://docs.typo3.org/p/friendsoftypo3/extension-builder/master/en-us/User/Index.html', '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::WARNING);
        $this->pdfgeneratorRepository->update($pdfgenerator);
        $this->redirect('list');

    }


    /**
     * Replaces the existing file with the new file in the file system
     *
     * @param File $existingFile
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $newFileReference
     * @return void
     */
    protected function replaceFile(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File $existingFile, \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $newFileReference)
    {
        $storage = $existingFile->getStorage();
        $folder = $existingFile->getParentFolder();
        $fileName = $existingFile->getName();

        // Delete the existing file
        if ($existingFile instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileInterface) {
            $storage->deleteFile($folder->getCombinedIdentifier() . $fileName);
        } else {
            die('not working');
        }
        // Import the new file into the storage
        $newFile = $this->resourceFactory->importUploadedFile(
            $newFileReference->getOriginalResource()->getOriginalFile(),
            $folder->getCombinedIdentifier(),
            $fileName
        );

        // Update the file reference with the new file
        $newFileReference->setOriginalResource($newFile);
    }
```